# Какой url передавать для авторизации яндекс директ в Google data studio connector

Tags: google-apps-script

Делаю коннектор для передачи показателей яндекс метрики в Google data studio. Создал скрипт на google apps scripts, в нем есть обязательная функция getOAuthService, в ней при создании сервиса используется метод "setAuthorizationBaseUrl", какой именно url требуется для него требуется?

```
  function getOAuthService() {
  // This is where we pull out the "client id" and "client secret" from the
  // Script Properties.
  Logger.log(oauth);
  var scriptProps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  Logger.log(scriptProps);
  var clientId = scriptProps.getProperty('OAUTH_CLIENT_ID');
  var clientSecret = scriptProps.getProperty('OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET');
  return OAuth2.createService('yandexDirect')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=token')
    .setTokenUrl('https://oauth.yandex.ru/verification_code')
    .setClientId(clientId)
    .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback');
}
```

На стороне яндекс сделал приложение с возможностью получения статистики, чтения параметров счетчиков

Comment: Вы примеры для этой либы смотрели?

Comment: Афтар, куда пропал?

Comment: Смотрел. Делал аналогично одному из примеров.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я автор примера. Создайте issue в репозитории, посмотрю что да как. Может быть для метрики все же другой url нужен?